# Skip Sections in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and this is my HTML (something similar structure wise):

```
<div class="fallpage">
 <div class="section">content</div>
 <div class="section ignore"></div>
 <div class="section">content</div>
 <div class="section ignore"></div>
 <div class="section">content</div>
</div>
```

I would like to skip the ignore sections. Ideally, hovering over them at the scrolling speed but not stopping at them like a normal section.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Demo online fullPage v2](https://jsfiddle.net/1kyuL4em/9/)
- [Demo online fullPage v3](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/yLVdNrb)

You could do this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange'],

    //events
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        if($('.fp-section').eq(index).hasClass('ignore')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(nextIndex + 1);
            })
            
        }
    }
});
```

Then add the class `ignore` to any section you want to skip:

```
<div class="section ignore"></div>
```

Comment: Worked great! but what about when you're going upwards.

Comment: Just modify the callback's logic.